# curl and Java program are treated differently by CouchDB

Tags: java, couchdb

This question might be a little bit naive...

I have written a small Java program that should query a CouchDB instance. However, CouchDB constantly returns that my user is not authorized. Using the same URL with curl works.

The Java Code:

```
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://admin:PASSWORD@localhost:5984/ecm_ng_nonpart/_security");
        request.addHeader("accept", "application/xml");

        try {
            System.out.println("Executing request " + request.getMethod() + " " + request.getUri());
            ClassicHttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(request);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The response:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not authorized to access this db."}
```

The curl output:

```
C:\Users\joche>curl -X GET http://admin:PASSWORD@localhost:5984/ecm_ng_nonpart/_security
{"members":{"roles":["_admin"],"names":["ecmnp","admin"]},"admins":{"roles":["_admin"],"names":["admin"]}}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same credentials? In code above in java you have password "PASSWORD" however in curl code you have password "admin123"

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I use the correct password.

Comment: Perhaps curl applies basic authentication automatically, and your Java code does not.   You could use wireshark to check on that.

Answer (score 0):

> Using the same URL with curl works.

Your posted information does not support this claim. Your URLs are different in the two cases.

Java: _sessions

```
  HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://admin:PASSWORD@localhost:5984/ecm_ng_nonpart/_sessions");
```

Curl: _security.

```
curl -X GET http://admin:PASSWORD@localhost:5984/ecm_ng_nonpart/_security
```

Comment: Right! It was too late for propper work. Either way, _security works with curl, but not with Java.

Comment: Well, we can only answer the question actually asked  :-)